# Gatling: How to change saved integer value

Tags: java, scala, performance, gatling, scala-gatling

Gatling: How to change saved integer value

I save number of getting elements as integer value.

```
    val getElements = exec(http("1. get_elements")
            .get("/apis/;version=0/elements/items?")
            .check(jsonPath("$.totalElements").ofType[Int].saveAs("total_elements"))
            .check(status.is(200))
            .headers(headers_common))
```

But I can not modify this value in another function, for example:

```
    .repeat("${total_elements}" / 100){
         .....
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/):

> Warning
>
> This Expression Language only works on String values being passed to
>   Gatling DSL methods. Such Strings are parsed only once, when the
>   Gatling simulation is being instantiated.
>
> For example queryParam("latitude", session => "${latitude}") wouldn’t
>   work because the parameter is not a String, but a function that
>   returns a String.
>
> Also, queryParam("latitude", "${latitude}".toInt) wouldn’t because the
>   toInt would happen before passing the parameter to the queryParam
>   method.
>
> The solution here would be to pass a function:

So you have to pass a function where you would use the [Session API](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/session_api/).
In your case:

```scala
repeat(session => session("total_elements").as[Int] / 100) { ... }
```